# Images in fancybox go out of frame in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fancybox

Fancybox works properly in all other browsers. Only IE can't show it properly. The problem is clearly illustrated in the following screenshots:

http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/481/subscreens.jpg

I can't figure this out. IE seems to work fluently on fancybox original website's examples.

Comment: can you post a test link to your page

Comment: yeah, its http://www.siurbtukai.lt/alpha/?fotogalerija

Comment: All versions of IE, or just IE6, or ... ?

Comment: IE6, IE7 and IE8. all of those have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if I can answer my own question. But since I figured out what the problem was. I feel like i should share.

The thing was, my page had no doctype declared. I added this piece of code and everything works now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```